# Why can't I access user after registering with Passport in Express?

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

I've implemented a registration form in a modal to save a user to my database and subsequently log them in. The user is indeed saved to my database, but the user object remains undefined.

Here is my setup in app.js

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
exphbs = require('express-handlebars'),
passport = require('passport'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
session = require('express-session'),
funct = require('./app/functions'),
dbconfig = require('./app/config/database'),
db = require('orchestrate')(dbconfig.db),
LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

//===============PASSPORT===============
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("serializing " + user.username);
    done(null, user.username);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    console.log("deserializing " + obj);
    done(null, obj);
});
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
{passReqToCallback: true}, //allows us to pass back the request to the callback
function (req, username, password, done) {
    funct.localReg(username, password)
        .then(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                console.log("REGISTERED: " + user.username);
                req.login(user, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                });
                done(null, user);
            }
            if (!user) {
                console.log("COULD NOT REGISTER");
                req.session.error = 'That username is already in use, please try a different one.'; //inform user could not log them in
                done(null, user);
            }
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err.body);
        });
    }
));

//===============EXPRESS================
// Configure Express
app.use(morgan('combined')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(session({secret: 'MisfireMedia_Appubator', saveUninitialized: true, resave: true}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
res.render('about');
});

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/about',
    failureRedirect: '/'
})
);
```

And here's my function.js (where funct.localReg is defined)

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt'),
Q = require('q'),
dbconfig = require('./config/database'), //config file contains all tokens and other private info
db = require('orchestrate')(dbconfig.db); //config.db holds Orchestrate token

exports.localReg = function (username, password) {
console.log(password);
var deferred = Q.defer();
var user = {
    "username": username,
    "password": password
};
//check if username is already assigned in our database
db.get('users', username)
    .then(function (result){ //case in which user already exists in db
        console.log('username already exists');
        deferred.resolve(false); //username already exists
    })
    .fail(function (result) {//case in which user does not already exist in db
        console.log(result.body);
        if (result.body.message == 'The requested items could not be found.'){
            console.log('Username is free for use');
            db.put('users', username, user)
                .then(function () {
                    console.log("USER: " + user);
                    deferred.resolve(user);
                })
                .fail(function (err) {
                    console.log("PUT FAIL:" + err.body);
                    deferred.reject(new Error(err.body));
                });
        } else {
            deferred.reject(new Error(result.body));
        }
    });

return deferred.promise;
};
```

The modal form is being submitted with code in custom.js:

```
$(function() {
$("button#signupsubmit").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/signup",
        data: $('form#signup').serialize(),
        success: function(msg){
            $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        },
        error: function(){
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
});
});
```

However, once the modal hides (on successful post) I try to log out the user and get "user is not defined". Also, attempting to display the username with

```
{{#if user}}
<p>Hi, {{user.username}}</p>
{{/if}}
```

just gives me "Hi,"

So any ideas on why I can't access the user? I'm not especially experienced with Node, Express, or Passport and I don't quite fully understand what's going on yet because most of this is copypasta from tutorials and whatnot ([specifically this one](https://orchestrate.io/blog/2014/06/26/build-user-authentication-with-node-js-express-passport-and-orchestrate/)). Any suggestions on what to look at or what I'm missing would be most excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you are exposing REST api from express and consuming it in client side using jQuery. After successful login user data are cached in passport session and i think you are returning data to jQuery which temporarily holds the data.

One possibility is that when you are perform any action in client side, (unless you keep calling backend to fetch data from passport session) the data is flushed out, it is no more there so that's the reason you are getting it as undefined.

In such cases best you can do or i would say that most of the modern websites are designed such that they store user session data as a `json web token(JWT)` in browser's local storage in encoded form. You can read about JWT [here](https://openid.net/specs/draft-jones-json-web-token-07.html). You can also see some example as in how exactly the encoded string looks like and can play around with it [here](http://jwt.io).

When user successfully logs in, write the data in browser's local storage and when he logs out, clear the token from local storage. This will save you from making unnecessary calls back and forth to server.
I actually implemented it using AngularJS [here](http://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-jwt-auth), concept is same doesn't matter which framework we use.

Comment: not consuming with jQuery. Only using jQuery to submit the form. Even cutting out the modal and placing the form directly in the body with a traditional submit button responds the same way. 

User gets registered and serialize is executed on the user, as shown in the terminal:

    `Username is free for use`
    `USER: [object Object]`
   `REGISTERED: johndoe@rabblerabble.com`
    `serializing johndoe@rabblerabble.com`

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue was with the serialization. I was serializing `user.username` instead of just `user` therefore `user.username` didn't exist.

I changed the serialize function to

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("serializing " + user.username);
    done(null, user);
});
```

and also made sure to change my route render from

```
res.render('about');
```

to

```
res.render('about', {user: req.user});
```

which allowed me to display the username in the `about` handlebars file as such

```
{{user.username}}
```